# Printing multiple Excel tabs as a PDF document

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf

I am trying to get multiple tabs of an Excel document to print as a multi-page PDF document.

I activate the tabs that I want to print, and the print preview is exactly as I want it.

Currently, it saves each page over the last one and I end up with a 1 page PDF (showing whatever the last tab was).

After searching, it seems that some people have resolved this by ensuring that all pages have the same print quality.

I have done this, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

I have tried saving as PDF and also printing PDF but I get the same 1-page result.

I am using Excel 2011 for Mac.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you selecting `Print entire workbook` when you click print?

Comment: No, because I only want to print 4 out of 6 tabs. So I am choosing "Active Sheets" but I have highlighted all 4 of the tabs that I want to print. All 4 show in the print preview.

Comment: well - it's not the most ideal solution, but if you're careful to not save it (or save it temporarily as another workbook), you could try deleting the sheets you don't want, and then `Print Entire Workbook` might give you what you need? Just don't save the result or delete the temporary copy and you'd still have the correct data afterwards (?)